# How to search for strings using method indexOf

Tags: java

14.11 (Searching Strings) Write an application that inputs a line of text and a search character and uses String method indexOf to determine the number of occurrences of the character in the text.
14.12 (Searching Strings) Write an application based on the application in Exercise 14.11  that inputs a line of text and uses String method indexOf to determine the total number of occurrences of each letter of the alphabet in the text. Uppercase and lowercase letters should be counted together. Store the totals for each letter in an array, and print the values in tabular format after the totals have been determined.
My problem now is that how can I determine occurrence of each letter in a word. For example, the word "occurrence", how many times each letter occurred in this word.

I've written my code to the best of my understanding, and my code can display the characters and returns their indexes in a tabular form. But that is not exactly what the questions required.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Searching
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Text: ");
    String text1 = input.nextLine();
    char[] text2 = text1.toCharArray();
    System.out.println("Character   Index");
    for(int i = 0; i < text2.length; i++)
    {
System.out.printf("%s%12d%n", text2[i],text1.indexOf(text2[i], i));
    }
}
}
```

I want the actual output to be in a tabular format. The word "occurrence", my code should display each letter and how many times it occurred.
LETTER          FREQUENCY
o               1
c               3
u               1
r               2
e               2
n               1

Comment: I am not really sure what your question is? it sounds like you want someone to write your code for  you

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok if you used a HashMap? Here's the solution for 14.12:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter text: ");
//So we only have to find lower case chars
String input = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();

//Add every single character in the word
//We use a LinkedHashMap instead of a HashMap to retain character order during printing.
LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> characterCount = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    characterCount.put(input.charAt(i), 0);
}

//Iterate from every character ranging from a - z
//It would be more ideal to iterate only over the characters
//in the word. But your requirement asked to iterate over the alphabet.
for(int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) {
    //This is the character we are currently searching for
    Character searchingFor = (char)i;
    int startingIndex = 0; int foundIndex = 0;
    //Search for the character in the string FROM a specfic index (startingIndex in this case)
    //We update startingIndex to a bigger index in the string everytime we find the character.
    while((foundIndex = input.indexOf(searchingFor, startingIndex)) != -1) {
        //it must be the index+1 so the next time it checks after the found character.
        //without the +1, it's an infinite loop.
        startingIndex = foundIndex + 1;
        //Update count to the current value + 1
        characterCount.put(searchingFor, characterCount.get(searchingFor) + 1);
    }


}

//Print the results
for(Character c : characterCount.keySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%s%12d%n", c, characterCount.get(c));
}

in.close();
```

Console output for the word "occurence":

```
Enter text: occurence
o           1
c           3
u           1
r           1
e           2
n           1
```